# Javascript the divisor

Tags: java

I know how to find the divisor of a given integer (other than 1):

```
let smallest_divisor n = 
    let rec aux n i = 
        if i < (n / 2) then n
        else if (i mod n == 0) then n
        else aux n (i + 1)
    in aux n 2;;
```

But how do I find its divisor (other than itself)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is, instead of starting at `2` and working upwards via `(i + 1)`, to start at `n / 2` and work downwards via `(i - 1)`.

Another approach is to write `biggest_divisor` in terms of `smallest_divisor`:

```
let biggest_divisor n = n / smallest_divisor n ;;
```

---

**Edited to add:** The second approach is actually more efficient in the average case, since small divisors are closer to zero than large divisors are to *n*/2. (If 2 is not a divisor, then the next-smallest possible divisor is 3, which is the very next one you try; if *n*/2 is not a divisor, then the next-biggest possible divisor is *n*/3, which involves iterating over *n*/6 possibilities.)

In a comment, you write that you don't want `biggest_divisor` to depend on `smallest_divisor`, for some reason. Personally, I think that's a mistake; but if you feel strongly about it, then your best option is probably to mimic the `n / smallest_divisor n` approach, by iterating up from `2` and then returning `n / i` when you find a divisor.

Incidentally, you can improve the performance of both approaches by aborting as soon as `i * i > n`, rather than waiting until `i > n / 2`. That way you only need to try √*n* possible values of *i*, rather than *n*/2 possible values of *i*, before detecting that *n* is prime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ruakh. The second approach works fine but I'd like to create a new program. I'm not sure I understand what you said. I tried this: `let smallest_divisor n = let rec aux n i = if i > (n / 2) then n else if (n mod i == 0) then i else aux n (i - 1) in aux n n / 2;;` It works fine with pair numbers but not with impair numbers.

Comment: @dabig800: `aux n n / 2` means `(aux n n) / 2`, which is not what you want. You need to write `aux n (n / 2)`. (Also, you can remove the `if i > (n / 2) then n else`, since it will no longer be possible for that to happen.)